# Automatic lines inserts in VSC

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I need help with Visual Studio Code. When i open php files in VSC, the software automatically insert line space under every line.
It's embarrassing because my code looks too spaced. Every time i delete interlines but VSC automatically reinsert lines when i open the file.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue please ?

[image]

Comment: lol, i would try to help you out but IDK what language your using.

Comment: I don't think VSCode actually adds spacing. Is it possible your files were previously saved with \r\n ? In the bottom-right corner of VSCode, look for `LF` or `CRLF` and change accordingly. [This might also help](https://qvault.io/clean-code/line-breaks-vs-code-lf-vs-crlf/)

Comment: Thank you Andrea, I didn't know this option existed. My issue is now solved thanks to you !